# Return boolean if a string is less than a certain number JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how to get the function to return true/false at once.

I have string I will split. If there's a "." and check if it less than 3 then will loop until the last value then return if it true else if false.

If one of the values exceeds 250, it will return false

```js
const splitString = "123.123.1".split(".");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var prefix = parseInt(splitString[i]);
  console.log(stringCheck(prefix))
}

function stringCheck(inputString) {
  if (inputString < 250) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to display if the string does not have any greater 250. if no greater than 250, it will display true once else if there is one greater than 250 it will display false

Comment: You can't return `true` and `false` at once. You can either return `true` or `false`.

Comment: I believe what you mean to say is you want to return false immediately if a value is greater than 250 and return true if no values are greater than 250

Answer (score 1):

> Im trying to display if the string does not have any greater 250

Looks like you over complicated things.

You need not to loop everything. Whenever you find something wrong, just return

```
function check(){
const splitString = "123.123.1".split(".");
for(var k in splitString){
   if(splitString[k] > 250){
    return false;
   }
  }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` function (or `.every`). I guess in this case you're checking if every value is less than 250, so you might do this:

```
const splitString = "123.123.1".split(".");
var allBelow = splitString.every(n => {
    var num = parseInt(n); // TODO decide how you want strings parsed into numbers
    return num <= 250;
})
```

allBelow will be true or false, depending on if every value is <= 250.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only return false when error

```js
function stringCheck(inputString) {
  let  parts = inputString.split(".");
  if (parts.length !== 3) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(parts[i]) > 250) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}  

let str = "123.249.1";
console.log(stringCheck(str))
str = "123.255.1";
console.log(stringCheck(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the values in an array and use the some functionality of array:

```js
const splitString = "123.251.1".split(".");
var exceeds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var prefix = parseInt(splitString[i]);
  exceeds.push(stringCheck(prefix));
}
console.log(exceeds);
console.log(exceeds.some(val => val === false));

function stringCheck(inputString) {
  if (inputString < 250) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```